# How to retrieve the current user ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web

I'm building a photo album. So, I want a photo to belong to a certain user. How can I get User ID?

```
var com = new SqlCommand("Insert into Photos (Photo, DatePublished, UserId)" +
    "values (@Photo, @DatePublished, @UserId)", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", pic);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatePublished", DateTime.Today);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", //what should be written here?);
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
lblStatus.Text = "Image Uploaded Sucessfully";
```

Or can you point out some other way to do this kind of belonging? Thank you.

Comment: Did you define the UserId column as an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Do you use Membership such as ASP.Net Identity, Membership Provider?

Comment: if this is a web application you can easily get the name of the user as well as split it out in regards to getting their username if the UserId column is a string.. if not then you need to do an additional query that would query that database and return the userid based on the username that logged in using `User.Identity.Name` also look into `PrincipalContext ` along with `UserPrincipal` Classes

Comment: @Steve, I did. But the thing is this very table declares UserId as a foreign key which in turn has a relation with a table called "Users". The latter has an IDENTITY column of UserId.

Comment: you need to use either `AD along with PrincipalContext` or write your own query where you can return the UserId based on `Environment.UserName` for example.. this is not that trivial

Comment: @MethodMan, My bad is I don't know what is an appropriate approach for me. Since my supervisor prevented me to use Membership API and Roles API, I had not been able to tell some other role provider from these two. What's best for me?

Comment: as long as you have a way to make use of Relational table which sounds like you do since you have mentioned that there is a foreignkey involved.. just create a simple Join on the two tables to return the UserId after they log in and store it in a Session variable then cast then use that value in the @UserId parameter value...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you had your user log in first :)

Assuming you did, at that time you should have stored off their ID in memory when you did the SELECT to check their credentials. Simply retrieve that value and use it for this query.

```
//Global state is a made up static class of course
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", GlobalState.CurrentUserId);
```